# Problems in Stereorectifyuncalibrated to Triangulate3D

Tags: opencv, 3d, computer-vision

In Opencv, there is a function stereorectifyuncalibrated(). In that, we have to provide parameter like Corresponding Feature points and image size.

But,for trainagulation we used triangulatet3d  function so for that we require Q matrix.But How to find Q matrix in uncalibrated images?

Why does we require Q matrix? I haven't found any perticular information about it.

Comment: without ever using the function, `stereorectifyuncalibrated` only computes the homographies between two images, I guess (from reading the documentation)! Maybe this helps you to compute/guess camera intrinsics, but I dont know ;)

Comment: `stereorectifyuncalibrated` implements this paper:
http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~hartley/Papers/joint-epipolar/journal/joint3.pdf maybe there you can see how 3D reconstruction is done after computing the rectification?!?

Comment: I got more insights on Q matrix and projection.Q matrix means disparity to depth mapping matrix. We can found disparity using STREROBM correspondence method.So converting it into depth is diffcult task.And How to generate Q matrix once we convert disparity to depth values?